# Why java.sql.DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader() is native?

Tags: java, jdbc, classloader, native-methods

The method `DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader()` in class `java.sql.DriverManager` [is declared as](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/DriverManager.java#DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader%28%29) `native`. I understand that all the class loaders references in an application are available in the current executing JVM. Also, my basic understanding about native method is that it's used to call the method defined in native libraries and they execute outside the JVM execution environment.

My question is, what is that needed by `DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader()` which requires its implementation to be native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My basic understanding about native method is that its used to call the method defined in native libraries

This is correct, native methods represent calls of the code that is part of a natively compiled library

> and they execute outside the JVM execution environment

That is what native methods typically do. That is, the native methods that Java users write. However, native methods are not limited in what they can do: once you're outside of JVM, you can do what you wish. In fact, Java's built-in classes such as [`Class<T>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java?av=f), heavily rely on the ability to do so, with dozens of `native` method sprinkled around their Java code.

One of these methods is package-private [`java.lang.Class<T>.getClassLoader0`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getClassLoader0%28%29) (yes, with a zero). The implementation of [`ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader%28%29) ultimately refer to this method, which queries the internals of JVM to fetch the class loader.

Note that `DriverManager` cannot forward the call to `ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader`, because that would return the `DriverManager`'s class loader (because `DriverManager` would be the caller of `getCallerClassLoader`). It is not possible for the `DriverManager` to repeat the "magic" of `ClassLoader`'s `getCallerClassLoader` either, because it is located in a different package (i.e. not in the `java.lang`), so `Class<T>.getClasLoader0` is not accessible. That is why it is forced to move the `getCallerClassLoader` into the `native` territory, where the native code can obtain the calling class and fetch its class loader without restrictions.

Comment: So, `DriverManager` needs the "magic" of `ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader` and hence the native method. That answers my question. This gives rise to another question as to what is that "magic" which `DriverManager` needs ? If you check the source code of `DriverManager` it eventually checks for class loader returned by native method and if found null uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` which is not native!

Comment: @Santosh `Thread` is in `java.lang`, it can (and it does) call `ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader()`, which [calls](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader%28%29) the same `getClassLoader0`, which is `native`.

Comment: Aaah! my bad. Should have seen the source code myself. Thanks.